# Run find and rsync from bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to run find with rsync command.
I followed the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rsync). 
When I run it from the command line it run okay.

```
find ./copy1 -mtime +14  -printf %P\\0 | rsync -avc --dry-run --files-from=- --from0 ./copy1 /home/shlo/copy1/
```

The problem started when I run it from bash script:

```
RSYNC_COM='find ./copy1 -mtime +14  -printf %P\\0 | rsync -avc --dry-run --files-from=- --from0 ./copy1 /home/shlo/copy1/'
output=$($RSYNC_COM 2>&1)
```

I get the error:

> find: paths must precede expression: |
>   Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

It look he thinks the rsync command is parameters in the find command.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You are using a relative path, that's the problem. Give find an absolute path as first argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the command to a variable. The `|` is no longer parsed as pipe "operator", but as a normal string.

```
# echo 123 | cat
123
# a="echo 123 | cat"
# $a
123 | cat
```

The `|` is invalid argument for `find`, so it returns an error.

Use a function:

```
rsync_com() {
         find ./copy1 -mtime +14  -printf %P\\0 |
         rsync -avc --dry-run --files-from=- --from0 ./copy1 /home/shlo/copy1/
}
output=$(rsync_com 2>&1)
```

Remember to always quote variable expansions. And never run a command created by an unescaped variable expansion.

The convention is that upper case variables are reserved to be exported variables.